# Tool for identifying swing components

Tags: java, swing

I was given the task to analyze a Swing application, so I can take over the maintenance in the future. However, there is no one who understands the application, which could explain the concepts. Therefore, I must now make a bit of reverse engineering ...

First I want to understand the GUI structure. For that I have thus begun to change code and then I started the GUI to look at what graphical component this has influence. So I could assign the classes to graphical components. This approach is relatively time consuming. That is why I was wondering if there is a tool, which allows you to click on graphical components and which then displays the information (name, class,..) of this component? Many thanks for the help.

Comment: http://www.swinginspector.com/index_en.htm

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Many thanks.